# Minimising weighted sum equation

Tags: algorithm, math

I am trying to implement a stereo algorithm which involves finding a value of b which minimises the following equation:

> Σ  (W(p,q)*|b - I(q)|)
>
> ​

where W(p,q) is a weighting for q, and I(q) is the intensity of q, and b is in the range of [0,1,2,...,254,255].

Anyway, I can do this manually by substituting every value of b in and working out the sum and returning the value of b which minimises this.

However, this is quite slow. Is there any other way of finding the solution?

e.g. 1

> minimise: 15|b-10| + 10|b-29| + 5|b-5|

e.g. 2

> minimise: 2|b-58| + 99|b-20| + 2|b-7| + 8|b-19|

Comment: Not to be too harsh, but how does this relate to C++? As it stands, this seems better suited for [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Look up Linear-programming (or Mixed-integer if b is discrete) and the classic tricks to incorporate abs (unsmooth in it's raw form). But yes, the question is somewhat short.

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze what happens to the energy when you change `b`, you will notice three different cases: For very small `b`, decreasing `b` results in an increase of the energy and increasing `b` results in a decrease of the energy. The opposite holds for large `b`. And then there is a range of `b` (possibly only a single number) where no change to `b` can decrease the energy. This is what you are looking for.

The solution to this kind of energies is the [weighted median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_median) of `I(q)` (weighted with `W(p, q)`).